# iphone camerOverlay for use with Alternate Reality applications

Tags: iphone, graphics, image-processing, augmented-reality

Does anyone know a way to take an image captured on the iphone's camera, and do some image processing (e.g. edge detection, skeletization), and then overlay parts of the processed image on the original image (e.g. only the highlighted edges).

More generically how do I create a UImage with transparency (do I just scale the image and overlay it with an alpha value, does UIImage support transparency like gifs do). I'm thinking that you could combine a UIImagePickerController with a background thread that [takes "screenshots"](http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/27/1188/) of the UIImagePickerController view and does image processing on it to detect various objects and provide an overlay augmented reality display.

There's an open source [simple image processing library](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/) for the iphone. The [demo shows an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oImMJ6p6mKE) of taking an original photo (of a sudoku board) and then overlaying the detected object in the original photo.

They explain some of the [high-level techniques on their blog](http://sudokugrab.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html) .

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV makes image overlays remarkably simple, and it's been [ported to the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv). With OpenCV you can choose to take screenshots as you considered or do image processing on a live stream, one frame at a time. Take a look at some of its tutorial programs, they're really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `UIImagePickerController.overlayView` property you might want to set:

```
// Create a new image picker instance:
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

// Set the image picker source:
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

// Hide the controls:
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

// Make camera view full screen:
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, 1, 1.12412);

// Create an overlay view
// this might need to either 1) be transparent, or 2) be of the other dimensions
OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.width, self.view.height)];

// Insert the overlay:
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```