# How i write my own C++ library for iphone application?

Tags: iphone

I want to make library using C++ for assigning and developing some image processing tasks. Can any one give me sample example on custom C++ library?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: iPhone & OpenCV: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv