# Getting OpenCV to work on the Iphone

Tags: xcode, ios, opencv

I tried to follow [these instructions](https://github.com/niw/iphone_opencv_test) get OpenCV to compile on my MAC MINI, but failed at step 6:

**../opencv_cmake.sh Simulator ../OpenCV-2.1.0**

I got these errors, and I can't make sense of it. Any clues?

```
Starting cmake...
Target SDK            = iPhoneSimulator
iOS SDK Version       = 4.1
iOS Deployment Target = 3.0
OpenCV Root           = ../OpenCV-2.1.0
OpenCV Install Prefix = /Users/haoest/Development/iphone_opencv_test/build_simulator/../opencv_simulator

-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-4.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler
  "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" is
  not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /Users/haoest/Development/iphone_opencv_test/build_simulator/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build

  "/Applications/CMake 2.8-4.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_progress_report
  /Users/haoest/Development/iphone_opencv_test/build_simulator/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
  1

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
  -isysroot
  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk
  -mmacosx-version-min="10.6" -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /Users/haoest/Development/iphone_opencv_test/build_simulator/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec

  "/Applications/CMake 2.8-4.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
  -isysroot
  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk
  -mmacosx-version-min="10.6" -Wl,-search_paths_first
  -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTryCompileExec

  ld: warning: in
  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib,
  file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

  Undefined symbols:

    "_exit", referenced from:
        start in crt1.10.6.o

  ld: symbol(s) not found

  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

  make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec] Error 1

  make: *** [cmTryCompileExec/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:39 (project)
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone and OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one: http://computer-vision-talks.com/2010/12/building-opencv-for-ios/

Answer (score 1):

You do realise that there's a pre-compiled version for you by Niwa (either via that github link or on his site http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en) where you can just open the Xcode opencv_test.proj file. It includes an example project to get you started, which you can build on from there. It works for both the iPhone device and the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is now available as a framework for iOS. Just drag and drop into your project. It supports video capture too. See the article and get the example project [here](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/).

Comment: hi, can you elaborate this, I am struggling in compilation process. thanks