# No such file or directory in opencv2

Tags: iphone, xcode, opencv

How to solve this error?

```
opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
```

I have tried out all the possibilities, but no success. Not only one file. But not any of **opencv2/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put "imgproc_c.h" in in "opencv2/imgproc" folder

Comment: See my updated question. I have put it, but getting same error.

Comment: you need to drag this file in xcode's file explorer .. are you putting this file in Finder.. when you drag and drop a file in xcode it will create a reference for it and use this ref. to find things

Comment: Also please post the reason of downvote in comments.. it will be helpful to other users

Comment: I am using OpenCV. Can you help me how to add OpenCV's Lib link and header search for OpenCV2?

Comment: have a look on this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv

Comment: also have a look on this great project (its using opencv) - https://github.com/beetlebugorg/PictureMe

Comment: Can you tell me how to set path for opencv2?