# How to use face detection in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

**How  to use face detection for the face image using iPhone camera** ?

I want to develop an application for iPhone in xcode and use  face  Image in the application to  but I do not know how it is possible to use face detection in my application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at openCV

Here is a link to the question asking something similar to your question
[iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv).

And i think you can find a template from this site

http://www.ient.rwth-aachen.de/cms/software/opencv/

Comment: Can you please let me know how it can be used.

Comment: @Mohit You can use open cv to detect face.

Comment: I have gone through the document but not able to install the framework:(

Comment: I guess the framework might not work in the current version on iOS SDK