# DETECT the Edge of a Document in iPhoneSDK

Tags: iphone, ios4, image-processing, edge-detection, object-detection

I am looking something like attached image, How can I implement this in iPhoneSDK.

Can anybody suggest me **some open source API** or **Algorithm Code** to detect the corners of captured image of a document.

Some How, I got an open source API called **OpenCV** which recognize the [Human Face](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en) very well. I want to use the same API if possible.Now the problem Is how can I make the changes in those static libraries according to my requirement to Scan the Document edges.
*Alternatively*,

**how to detect for the square/rectangle object in the captured image ?**

[image]

Comment: If you go the opencv route, you should look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection) question

Comment: I'm facing same problem. share resolve steps and guide me to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are already using openCV you might know the Reference Manual:

http://www.sciweavers.org/books/opencv-open-source-computer-vision-reference-manual

On page 10-6 there is a reference to the set of contour detection functions:

```
CvContourScanner cvStartFindContours(IplImage* img, 
                                     CvMemStorage* storage, 
                                     int headerSize, 
                                     CvContourRetrievalMode mode, 
                                     CvChainApproxMethod method );

int cvFindContours( IplImage* img, 
                    CvMemStorage* storage,
                    CvSeq** firstContour, 
                    int headerSize=sizeof(CvContour),
                    CvContourRetrievalMode mode=CV_RETR_LIST,
                    CvChainApproxMethod method=CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
```

I hope that helps.

When the target of your question was, how to use OpenCV on ios/iPhone then you can have a look at the following Sites. Ready made XCode project files for use in an iOS project:

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/

Another StackOverflow post with very valuable information can be found here:

[iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

Comment: It's the same link from where I donwload the framework.BTW let me check out with the book, if I can get something workout.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I got these methods, but it's quite difficult to trace down for it, as based on which paramters framework is Recognizing the Face ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you really want to know. Maybe the online Wiki of OpenCV for face detection helps you: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection