# Detect edge of a document in windows phone

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone, edge-detection

I need to detect the corner/edge of a document in a captured image in Windows Phone 7. I cannot use openCV as WP 7 does not have support for native code lib.

Can anybody suggest me some algorithm or open source library that I can use for this purpose.

I want to do the similar thing on Windows Phone app as posted in another SO question: [DETECT the Edge of a Document in iPhoneSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921256/detect-the-edge-of-a-document-in-iphonesdk)

Comment: One easy method for edge detection is called sobel, one easy method for corner detection is the Harris operator. They are easy to implement. After you get comfortable with them, you can advance to Canny's edge detector, which isn't hard to implement either. This is assuming you want to implement the algorithms, otherwise you can search for ready implementations.

Comment: Thanks mmgp. I actually did not find any WP compatible library for use. But I can find some C++/C# example. My idea is to port one of them for WP.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using A-Forge for this task.
the A-forge .NET have great functionality and I think it will not be a problem to use it on windows phone