# Video image processing tools and resources for iPhone/ios

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, opencv, signal-processing

I am working on developing an iOS video app that needs to do stuff like apply filters, adjust brightness/contrast/saturation add overlays etc. As I am new to image processing I am not able to judge which resources (i.e. APIs, open source libraries) I can use. So any guidance from those who have experience in this field will be of great help.

Comment: You can use OpenCV. It is available for iphone. look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great tutorial about GPU-accelerated video processing on Mac and iOS: 
http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios

Comment: Based on that work, I developed a full framework for accelerated image and video processing: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage , so I'd now direct people to that.

Comment: Brad's GPUImage is what you should be using for realtime video processing, like brightness adjustment and so on. You could roll your own, but that would take long time. Doing that sort of processing on the GPU is the only way to get fast execution of video processing logic on iOS. You might also want to have a look at my AVAnimator library if you want to support lossless video, need a full alpha channel, or you want to do seamless looping and other animation logic.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)**.

**1. Get OpenCV**

Check out [OpenCV homepage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) to download OpenCV source.

**2. Check out this SOF for more details on OpenCV on iOS**

[iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

**3. Get and read some good books on OpenCV**

The best book on OpenCV is "**[Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)**" written by Gary Bradsky, main founder of OpenCV.

Second one is "**[OpenCV cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/opencv-2-computer-vision-application-programming-cookbook/book)**".

These books contains lots of examples on OpenCV along with description

**4. Check out [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/)**.

OpenCV documentation contains details of complete functions. It also includes a lot of **[tutorials](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)**, which are really good for all.

**5. Also try running OpenCV samples. It contains a lot of good programs**

All the best.

Comment: I am checking this. But why is OpenCV necessary when there is openGL ES support already built in iOS?