# Is there a way to detect facial features on a video?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, video, face-detection

I'm trying to find out if there are any libraries or frameworks that will help with detecting facial features i.e. the eyes while video recording.

I tried using face.com api and THE  CIDetector on IOS, but they only work on Images not video.

P.S. I'm developing for the iphone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply extract frames from the video as it is playing and use those in the `CIFaceDetector`? This site has some good info on how to get frames from video files on iOS:

http://www.7twenty7.com/blog/2010/11/video-processing-with-av-foundation

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this on iOS/Mac OSX, but you should check the [OpenCV library](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/).
Check this question for iOS support: [iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

The library has built-in functions to detect faces, but I don't know if they are available on the iOS port.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for **Object detection** and I would recommend **OpenCV**.

If you want an out-of-the-box example just check out this [link](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/face-tracking/) :) There is fully functional sample code attached to the tutorial. You can use OpenCV for a lot more stuff than just face tracking – just dig into the [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/index.html) and some [tutorials](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html).

You can finde several cascade classifier [here](http://mozart.dis.ulpgc.es/Gias/modesto.html?lang=0#downloads) for partial face detection.