# open source library to construct panoramic photos on iOS?

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, panoramas

Does any one know of such library? I want to play with this functionality on an iPhone but dont want to write the code from scratch. PanoramaGL doesn't help as it only deals with displaying the panorama rather than building it.

Hope to hear from u soon
Cheere
Fadi

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex a job you want to do the Opencv library has a [panorama stitching](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/opencv_stitching)  module. Opencv now runs on iOS, see [iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

see a [Panoramic](https://github.com/SpotMetrix/Panoramic) it opensource help you.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is helpful, but there is actually already a panoramic camera coded into iOS. you have to edit a plist file on a jailbroken device to enable it, though.