# Implement Panorama feature in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, panorama-control

I have to implement the `Panorama feature` in my ios app. Is there any `library or source code` for this?

I know there are many questions on this but can't able get much idea about this.

Help me if any one knows.

Comment: see this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6

Comment: look at the google search link added in my comment

Comment: Check these ques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062932/libraries-to-capture-panorama-in-ios-6
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791151/open-source-library-to-construct-panoramic-photos-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [PanoramaGL](http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/) . It perfectly works on iPhone,iPad,iPod and Android.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but it does not capture the image from the camera.

Comment: It can't capture images,It can just display your panorama images in panaromic view.

Comment: how can i give images as panoramic for view?

Comment: you can capture images using iPhone and then access them accordingly to show it using PanoramaGl library.the working example is given for predefined images,please download it and try it once.

Comment: error `No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64).`

Comment: Go to `project menu` -> `active target(in xcode)` and change the base sdk to `4.0`

Comment: but i don't have sdk 4.0 installed.