# IOS - Image number detection (OCR)

Tags: ios, ocr, detection

I m looking for any open source of image number detection (or OCR),
so far, I've found "Tesseract".

Does anyone know something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: image number means can you upload screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV([iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)) and ABBY (http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/ios/)