# Wikitude/AR SDK's to Pick out objects in 3d space

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality, vuforia, wikitude

[image]

Im looking at integrating an AR Kit into our iOS App so we can use the camera to scan a room or field of view for objects. Above is an example of what i mean, if you were to bring up the camera it would highlight the separate objects in the room and allow them to be clicked and "added" into the system.

Does anyone know if this is achievable with the current AR kits or anything else out there? It all seems to be the fact that objects that you are looking for have to be pre-defined and loaded into a database so the app can find them. Im hoping it should be able to pick out the objects realtime. It doesnt need to actually know any details on the actual object just so that can be pulled off the base scenary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library ([iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)) contains many algorithms to compare different image blobs. If you want to match some simple template to find objects then try Viola & Jones algorithm and so called Haar cascades. OpenCV has trained collection of templates in XML files for detecting faces for example. OpenCV contains utility for training thus you are able to generate cascades for other kinds of objects.

Some example projects:

https://github.com/alexmac/alcexamples/blob/master/OpenCV-2.4.2/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.rst Cascade Classifier Training
https://github.com/lukagabric/iOS-OpenCV Example code for detecting Colors and Circle shapes
https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial Feature Detection (SURF, ORB, FREAK)
https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquaresSL Square Detection using Pyramid scaling, Canny, contours, contour simpification